# How to browse pdffile open into html iframe

Tags: javascript

```js
function onFileSelected(event) {
  var selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  var result = document.getElementById("result");
  reader.onload = function(event) {
    result.innerHTML = event.target.result;
  };
  reader.readAsText(selectedFile);
}
```

```html
<input type="file" accept="application/pdf" onchange="onFileSelected(event)">
<iframe id="result" height="300" width="600"></iframe>
```

This code can't work plz help to solve.

Try to browse pdf file open into html iframe tag

Comment: `result.innerHTML` actually does nothing, because you need to change `src` of `iframe` to change it's content. Try uploading it to temporary dir and than change url to this dir.

Comment: OK i try sir'''